# Python Grid manager within a frame

Tags: python, grid

[image: My example - Grid layout not placing the items a[![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FGOE.png)s expected](https://prntscr.com/py5amm)

```
labelframe1 = LabelFrame(top,height=100,width=400)
labelframe1.grid(row=0,column=0)
firstlabel = Label(labelframe1, text="How was the device being used?")
q1_button = ttk.Radiobutton(firstlabel,text="male",value='male',var=gender)
q1_button2 = ttk.Radiobutton(firstlabel,text="male",value='female',var=gender)
firstlabel.grid(row=2,column=2)
q1_button.grid(row=1,column=0)
q1_button2.grid(row=1,column=1)
```

I am trying to place a lable and buttons within a frame and my label is not showing at row=0. I have benn trying to get better at using this .grid I don't understand what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: This should read: `ttk.Radiobutton(labeframe1, ...`

Comment: Thanks that fixed my issue - I am taking classes on udemy, thank you so much for the answer!